# Sending an HTML email programmatically or through free applications

Tags: python, html, email

I am attempting to send an HTML email in Python. I find that email browsers(not sure if thats the correct term) change my html/css especially concerning images. Such as if I have the following CSS:

```
.myclass { background-image: url(http"//mywebsite.com/images/img1.png }
```

In Microsoft Outlook, it removes that line of CSS, so...:

```
.myclass {}
```

In gmail's browser the layout of my HTML is not shown(its 2 columns) but gmail shows the 2 divs above each other.

**I only need to send this email once, its an invitation to an event. And it doesn't need to be done programmatically or just through python.**

Do you know of the easiest way to send a html email that contains images(preferably references images on my website & not attached to the email)? Whats the way that has the least headaches? Any open source programs that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/19/design-and-build-an-email-newsletter-without-losing-your-mind/

Hope this helps.